# Javascript: this reference within a property function

Tags: javascript, function, this, prototype

This is intended to use on the browser.

```
function keyboardJS () {
    this.keys = {};
    this.tempASCIIkey;
    this.tempCHARkey;
}
keyboardJS.prototype = {
    keyIsUp : function (evt) {
      console.log(this);
      this.ASCIIkey = evt.keyCode;
      this.CHARkey = String.fromCharCode(this.ASCIIkey);
      this.keys[this.CHARkey] = false;
      console.log(this.CHARkey + " is now " + this.keys[this.CHARkey]);
    },
    keyIsDown : function (evt) {
      console.log(this);
      this.ASCIIkey = evt.keyCode;
      this.CHARkey = String.fromCharCode(this.ASCIIkey);
      this.keys[this.CHARkey] = true;
      console.log(this.CHARkey + " is now " + this.keys[this.CHARkey]);
    },
    init : function () {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyIsDown);
      document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyIsUp);
    }
}

var game = {};

game.myKeyboard = new keyboardJS();
game.myKeyboard.init();
```

However, (console.log(this);) returns "#document". How do I reference the object's properties within a prototype function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
init : function () {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyIsDown.bind(this));
  document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyIsUp.bind(this));
}
```

The `this` isn't magically bound when you pass a reference to a function, and in this context with `addEventListener()`, the `this` is what it is meant to be.

Note that `bind()` isn't supported by our favourite older IEs.

You can shim it, pass functions which call your functions on your prototype or use a library that has a bind equivalent (`_.bind()` in Underscore, `$.proxy()` in jQuery, etc).

Comment: Works like magic! Thanks!

I shall investigate the bind() function, in order to deeply understand why this works.

Comment: @Dan I don't know why I chose that horribly misappropriate word. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I will! Thank you for solving the doubt :)